# Java - Running jarfile makes program not responding

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a JavaFX application that runs a jarfile and gets it's (error) input stream and then repaints a label with it. In order to do that ,  (because of a loop,) I implemented the Platform.runLater(Runnable); . Whenever I am running the jarfile , the program immediately stops responding. (The program is a remake of a JFrame application.There it worked smoothly , but I was using Threads.)Here is the part of the code that causes trouble:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
        try{
            data.updateConsole("Starting server!");
            //String fileDir = data.dir + File.separator + "craftbukkit.jar";
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -Xmx2048M -jar "+"craftbukkit.jar"+" -o true --nojline");
            data.setOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
            is = proc.getErrorStream();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader readr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        data.setServerStarted(true);
        String line;
        try {
        while(data.serverStarted()){    
                if((line = readr.readLine()) != null){
                    data.updateConsole(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                readr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
                }});
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running the "java -jar" on the platform thread, you're blocking the UI from refreshing. You should create a separate thread to run the "java -jar" logic, then use runLater to update the label only.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. I have been trying to do it for quite some time *.*